# Extract date and name in Oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, substring, regex-replace

I have `prg_tbl` table in which i insert filenames from directory in the column `Filename` and values are stored in column `Filename` as :

```
TRG_jira_creditentity_20220426.csv
TRG_jira_CRL_Boni_20220426.csv
TRG_jira_CRL_Branchen_20220426.csv
TRG_jira_CRL_Counterparty_20220426.csv
TRG_jira_CRL_KNE_20220426.csv
TRG_jira_CRL_Länder_20220426.csv
```

In one select query i want to extract date from this rows for example `'20220426'`. And in another select query i want to extract filename for example `'TRG_jira_creditentity_'`.

I am not sure how to do this using select query as the dates from filename gets changes but the prefix which is part of filename it remains static for example `'TRG_jira_creditentity_'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use [**`REGEXP_REPLACE()`**](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/REGEXP_REPLACE.html) function such as

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(filename,'^(.*_)([^.]*).*','\2') AS col1,
       REGEXP_REPLACE(filename,'[^_]+$') AS col2       
  FROM prg_tbl
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=9c6c5f2694d5ba45be6b147a06b1e96c)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

You want to use regular expressions (regexes).  For example:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR( 'TRG_jira_creditentity_20220426.csv',
    'TRG_jira_creditentity_(\d+)\.csv', 1, 1, NULL, 1 ) from dual;
```

returns

```
20220426
```

Here we search for the pattern `\d+` which means "one or more digits" after the string `TRG_jira_creditentity_`.

There are [many tutorials on regexes out there](https://neeva.com/search?q=regex+tutorial&src=nvobar), but note that all regex implementations are slightly different, and Oracle especially.  Probably the best place to start would be the Oracle docs themselves, such as [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/appdev.101/b10795/adfns_re.htm), depending on what version of Oracle you're running.

Comment: sorry but in your answer you have hardcoded the value instead of that i want to use column name ..how to do that ?

Comment: Replace the value with the column name.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using (fast) string functions (rather than slow regular expressions):

```sql
SELECT SUBSTR(value, 1, INSTR(value, '_', -1)) AS file_name,
       TO_DATE(
         SUBSTR(value, INSTR(value, '_', -1) + 1, 8),
         'YYYYMMDD'
       ) AS dt
FROM   table_name
```

If you do want to use (slower) regular expressions then you can use the same pattern `^(.*_)(\d{8}).csv$` for both parts and extract the different capturing groups:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(value, '^(.*_)(\d{8}).csv$', 1, 1, NULL, 1) AS file_name,
       TO_DATE(
         REGEXP_SUBSTR(value, '^(.*_)(\d{8}).csv$', 1, 1, NULL, 2),
         'YYYYMMDD'
       ) AS dt
FROM   table_name
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (value) AS
SELECT 'TRG_jira_creditentity_20220426.csv'     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'TRG_jira_CRL_Boni_20220426.csv'         FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'TRG_jira_CRL_Branchen_20220426.csv'     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'TRG_jira_CRL_Counterparty_20220426.csv' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'TRG_jira_CRL_KNE_20220426.csv'          FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'TRG_jira_CRL_Länder_20220426.csv'       FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

> | FILE_NAME | DT |
> | --- | --- |
> | TRG_jira_creditentity_ | 2022-04-26 00:00:00 |
> | TRG_jira_CRL_Boni_ | 2022-04-26 00:00:00 |
> | TRG_jira_CRL_Branchen_ | 2022-04-26 00:00:00 |
> | TRG_jira_CRL_Counterparty_ | 2022-04-26 00:00:00 |
> | TRG_jira_CRL_KNE_ | 2022-04-26 00:00:00 |
> | TRG_jira_CRL_Länder_ | 2022-04-26 00:00:00 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f4aceed9d5c34c95ac671e01c368e5a0)*